# Using ls, how to list files without printing the extension (the part after the dot)?

Tags: bash, ls

Suppose I have a directory with some files:

```
$ ls
a.c  b.c  e.c  k.cpp  s.java
```

How can I display the result without the file extension(the part following the dot, including that dot)? Like this:

```
$ <some command>
a
b
e
k
s
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

using sed?

```
ls -1 | sed -e 's/\..*$//'
```

Comment: FWIW, I'd use `ls | sed 's/\(.*\)\..*/\1/'` to only strip off the part starting with the *last* dot. (Also, watch out for `.` in a directory name, eg. ls ../src

Comment: ls -1 and ls behave identically when stdout for ls is a pipe.  Doesn't matter really...

Comment: @rici: `sed -e 's/\.[^.]*$//'`

Comment: @anishsane, yeah, or that. `s:\.[^./]*$::` would be even better.

Answer (score 15):

```
ls | while read fname 
do
    echo ${fname%%.*}
done
```

Try that.

Comment: [don't parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) -- `for fname in *; do ...`

Comment: @Glenn - That is a correct approach,  yes. The UUOC concept.  I thought the OP implied using ls.   So apparently did  Dyno Hungjun Fu.

Comment: THIS IS WHAT I HAVE BEEN SEARCHING FOR!!! WOW THANK YOU!!!! :)))) <33333

Answer (score 9):

```
ls -a | cut -d "." -f 1
```

man (1) cut

Very handy, the -d switch defines the delimiter and the -f which field you want.

EDIT: Include [riverfall's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5039637/riverfall) scenario is also piece of cake as cut can start also from the end, though the logic is somewhat different. Here an example with a bunch of files with random names, some with two dots, some  with a single dot and some without extension:

```
runlevel0@ubuntu:~/test$ ls
test.001.rpx  test.003.rpx  test.005.rpx  test.007.rpx  test.009.rpx  testxxx
test.002.rpx  test.004.rpx  test.006.rpx  test.008.rpx  test_nonum    test_xxx.rtv


runlevel0@ubuntu:~/test$ ls | cut  -d "." -f -2
test.001
test.002
test.003
test.004
test.005
test.006
test.007
test.008
test.009
test_nonum
testxxx
test_xxx.rtv
```

Using the minus *before* the field number makes it eliminate all BUT the indicated fields (1,2 in this case) and putting it behind makes it start counting from the end.

This same notation can be  used for offset and characters besides of fields (see the  man page)

Comment: filenames can have more than 1 dot, especially rpm packages

Comment: Can anyone tell me why ls | cut  -d "." -f -2 > test.txt does not work?

Comment: no idea mate. I have no idea what you expect to see. I assume that you are aware that you have to read the file with `cat`, right?

Answer (score 1):

If you already know the extension of the file, you can use [`basename`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/basename), from the man page:

> basename - strip directory and suffix from filenames

Unfortunately, it's mostly useful if you're trying to filter a single extension, in your case the command is:

```
basename -s .c -a $(ls *.c) && basename -s .cpp -a $(ls *.cpp) && basename -s .java -a $(ls *.java)
```

output:

```
a
b
e
k
s
```

Answer (score 0):

```sh
for f in *; do printf "%s\n" ${f%%.*}; done
```

[Why it works?](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html)

> `${string%%substring}` Deletes longest match of $substring from back of $string.

This would handle `mypackage.pkg.tar.xz` --> `mypackage` for instance.

In contrast:

> ${string%substring} Deletes shortest match of $substring from back of $string.

That is `${string%substring}` would only delete the final extension, i.e.
`mypackage.pkg.tar.xz` --> `mypackage.pkg.tar`

On a side note, use `printf` preferentially to `echo`. The syntax is a little more complex, but it will work on a wider variety of systems.

If you only want to see files, not directories:

```sh
for f in *; do if [[ -f ${f} ]]; then printf "%s\n" ${f%%.*}; fi; done
```